# Passing arguments to a bc script

Tags: bc

I'm looking for a way to pass command line arguments to a bc script.

For example, take this simple bc script that outputs 10 digits of pi (rounded):

```c
#!/bin/bc -lq

n_digits = 10;

scale = n_digits + 1;

/* calculation, replace later with a better algorithm */
result = 4 * a(1);                /* arctan(1) = pi/4 */

/* rounding to n_digits */
t = 10^scale;
result *= t;
if (result < 0) result -= 50; /* unnecessary, but generally useful */
if (result > 0) result += 50; /* always true in this specific case */
scale -= 2;
result /= t;

print result, "\n";

quit;
```

In the script the variable `n_digits` is hard coded to 10. I'd like to pass it a value from the command line. I could use the `read()` function (`n_digits = read();`) to pass it a number from the standard input like this:

```
$ ./pi <<< 20
3.1415926535897932385
```

But this requires trickery with redirection or piping and is not very user friendly. A command line argument would be much better.

The workaround I can think of is embedding the bc script into a bash script, like this, for example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

bc -lq << EOF
n_digits = $1;
scale = n_digits + 1;

/* calculation, replace later with a better algorithm */
result = 4 * a(1);                /* arctan(1) = pi/4 */

/* rounding to n_digits */
t = 10^scale;
result *= t;
if (result < 0) result -= 50; /* unnecessary, but generally useful */
if (result > 0) result += 50; /* always true in this specific case */
scale -= 2;
result /= t;

print result, "\n";

quit;
EOF
```

This works, but is bad aesthetic, and it feels unnecessary. Also, it looks like it could be used to inject arbitrary code, so it might be a good idea to implement checks in the bash script. Messy...

**My question is:** Is it possible to do it directly with a bc script? Is there some kind of an argv variable that I just can't find in documentation?

I'm using GNU bc, btw.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do that with GNU `bc`, but the BSD `bc` and any bc compatible with that have a way: the `-e` option.

Comment: Hi, @Kresimir! Did you find an answer? I'm trying to solve this problem as well.

Comment: Hi, @JegorsČemisovs, it seems there is no solution, with GNU bc, at least. The bash wrapper above is the best I still have, 3 years later.